# Chrome printing some textboxes with grey fill

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been running into an issue with Chrome where some textboxes on my page print with a grey fill, even though they're white when viewing the page normally. I've tried using `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;`, as I've seen with some other printing issues in Chrome, but that didn't help. I've also noticed that it's somewhat inconsistent. For example, it happens when I print the full page of [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdmg5uc7/17/), but not when I print [just the result](https://jsfiddle.net/sdmg5uc7/17/show/).

This only happens in Chrome, and none of the other browsers I've tried (IE and Firefox).

The only thing I've really figured out about it is that it is somehow tied to the borders of the textbox, because the color it prints with appears to be the same color as (most of) the borders. But even this is somewhat inconsistent in that it doesn't seems to always be connected to the same border.

Can anyone help me understand (and, hopefully fix) this issue?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm hoping for a fix from an html/CSS standpoint. This issue also happens to others in the office and some users of the affected pages, it's not just an issue with my own machine. Although, again, it appears to be inconsistent in who is affected by it.

**Edit 2:** [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9iV2elPP2ikL50FSPHTktJiplbsHaws/view?usp=sharing) is a pdf of what the end result (with grey boxes) looks like

A snip of which is:

[image]

Comment: Just double checked with a utility to get the color. It's the same color code (#696969) as the borders for the textboxes in the fiddle I linked in the question.

Comment: Have you tried setting `background-color: white;` on the offending elements?

Comment: I somehow hadn't thought to try that yet (thinking zebras instead of horses, maybe), but it didn't help either.

Comment: Nononono! #696969 is the grey that I'm getting. The textboxes printing correctly (in white) are still #FFFFFF, as they should be.

Comment: Is the an `@media print` rule being applied to some of the elements? Maybe in a different CSS file? I think there is somewhere in the Chrome developer tools to set the media to print so that you can check that more easily.

Comment: Thank you for that! And no, it doesn't look like there are any `@media print` rules that are responsible. But that dev tools option for setting the media to print is new to me and very useful.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the transition? I assume you're using Windows - do you have an Ubuntu virtual machine available that you can try Chromium in? It's fantastic how a browser *cough*firefox*cough* can have different problems on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not understand why this is happening, but honestly I just suggest re-installing chrome. Probably just some bug from one of your extensions or etc, if you do not want to re-install chrome, just try and delete some of your extensions.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a local issue. Others in my office as well as users of the affected pages experience it as well.

Comment: I tried going on the fiddle you sent ant there were no problems, so honestly it is probably a chrome bug, so just wait for the next update, or report it to google